# WlanClent.cs is showing error of too many sessions

Tags: c#

I am using SimpleWifi.dll (https://www.nuget.org/packages/SimpleWifi) and trying to fetch one of the SSID and it's RSSI from the list, I am getting below exception when I try to fetch it continuously for 10th to 11th time-

```
An attempt was made to establish a session to a network server, but there are already too many sessions established to that server
```

Can anyone help me how to get rid of it?

Below is the section of the code what I tried-

```
public int GetRSSI(string SSID)
        {
            int strength = -1;
            WlanClient client = new WlanClient();
            // Wlan = new WlanClient();
            try
            {
                foreach (WlanClient.WlanInterface wlanIface in client.Interfaces)
                {

                    Wlan.WlanBssEntry[] wlanBssEntries = wlanIface.GetNetworkBssList();

                    foreach (Wlan.WlanBssEntry network in wlanBssEntries)
                    {
                        int rss = network.rssi;
                        //     MessageBox.Show(rss.ToString());
                        byte[] macAddr = network.dot11Bssid;

                        string tMac = "";

                        for (int i = 0; i < macAddr.Length; i++)
                        {

                            tMac += macAddr[i].ToString("x2").PadLeft(2, '0').ToUpper();

                        }


                        if (System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(network.dot11Ssid.SSID).ToString().Trim('\0') == SSID)
                        {
                            strength = (int)network.rssi;
                            break;
                        }
                        //MessageBox.Show("Found network with SSID: " + System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(network.dot11Ssid.SSID).ToString());

                        //MessageBox.Show("Signal: " + network.linkQuality);

                        //MessageBox.Show("BSS Type: " + network.dot11BssType);

                        //MessageBox.Show("MAC: " + tMac);

                        //MessageBox.Show("RSSID: " + rss.ToString());


                    }
                    //Console.ReadLine();
                }
                return strength;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return 0;
            }
            finally
            {

            }

        }
```

Comment: You probably are not closing the connection(releasing the resources after reading from them)! Sounds bad practice.

Comment: How Can i do it for the same? I am new to this one.

Comment: Are you calling GetRSSI() in a loop? If so, then add something like `client.close();` in the finally block. NOTE : I'm not aware of SimpleWiFi .